# Algabreic manipulation with complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How does $(iwl + \frac{1}{iwc})^2$ equal to $(wl - \frac{1}{wc})^2$?

Let me clarify. In physics there is the impedance which is a complex number
$ Z = R + iwl + 1/iwc$

$R, w, l,$ and $c$, are constants; $i = \sqrt-1$
According to my book: $|Z| = \sqrt{R^2 + (wl - \frac{1}{wc})^2}$

The real part of $Z$ (i.e. R) squared gives $R^2$; the imaginary part squared gives the second term under the root, but I don't get how they're equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not:

$$\left( iwl + {1 \over iwc} \right)^2 = \left( iwl - {i \over wc} \right)^2 = i^2 \left( wl  - {1 \over wc} \right)^2 = - \left( wl - {1 \over wc} \right)^2$$

Comment: I clarified the question

Comment: In which case yes, because for any complex number $z$ can be written as $z = a + bi$ for $a, b$ real, and has modulus $z = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. Now apply that formula to your $Z$.